# Some one access my site using fake domain

Tags: asp.net, dns

One site(abc.com) developed using ASP.net, some one access this site using fake domain(stg_abc.com).Also changes made to our site affect that fake site.

Is there any way by which we can restrict this access currently and also in future...

Thanks

Comment: what do you call "fake domain", and how would changes to your site affect "that fake site"? How would same changes to your site be any better if that wasn't from a "fake domain", that is, how would restricting make it any better?

Comment: fc_google.com and i am able to access google.com, this scenario here...

Comment: some services which want to ascertain that a client connects from an ip address which matches its domain it claims to be from, is by doing a reverse DNS lookup on its ip address, and compare the result against what client claims. This is rather commonly done by mail server, wishing to verify the identity of the sending server.